# Mass Transit and Azure service bus: message consumed multiple times by different dev spaces

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-dev-spaces

I'm publishing a message after registering in this way (comments line are many attempts done).
I pass a queuePrefix in order to use different dev spaces, one per developer, since the application is microservices based.
Masstransit decouples the information exchange by different microservices

```
           this IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator cfg, IServiceProvider provider, string queuePrefix = null,
           Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>> configure = null)
           where TConsumer : class, IConsumer<TCommand>
           where TCommand : class
        {

            string queueName = $"{queuePrefix}-{typeof(TCommand).Name}";
            cfg.Message<TCommand>(configureTopology => {
                //configureTopology.SetEntityName(queueName);
                //configureTopology.UsePartitionKeyFormatter(context => context.Message.CustomerId);
            });
            cfg.Publish<TCommand>(configureTopology => {
                configureTopology.EnablePartitioning = true;
                //configureTopology.UsePartitionKeyFormatter(context => context.Message.CustomerId);
            });
            cfg.Send<TCommand>(x =>
            {
                //x.UsePartitionKeyFormatter(context => context..Message.CustomerId);
            });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, endpointCfg =>
            {                
                endpointCfg.RemoveSubscriptions = true;                
                endpointCfg.EnablePartitioning = true;
                endpointCfg.Consumer<TConsumer>(provider, configure);
            });
            return cfg;
        }
```

I though the prefix was enough, but if I publish a message, all the dev spaces consume the message.
What should I do? I've tried subscription without success. It seems I've taken the wrong path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that each message type has the same topic name, and all dev spaces are subscribing to the same topics. You can override the topic names similar to how you override the queue names to include a prefix by creating your own `IEntityNameFormatter`, similar to how it was done in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57923465/1882).

MassTransit includes an entity name formatter, `PrefixEntityNameFormatter`, which was added in v7, that does the same thing, you just need to specify it on your bus configuration for message topology.

```
cfg.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(
    new PrefixEntityNameFormatter(cfg.MessageTopology.EntityNameFormatter, "Frank-"));
```

Comment: It seems working locally, not on UAT! I'm quite confident it's because I need to update all the dev-spaces. Little testing before accpeting the answer! One more things. Since you're talking about Topic, and how MassTransit internally manage these stuff with Azure Service Bus is hidden and I haven't found any specs in docs, one more question: is using one topic per devspace a good practice, in order to divide all the subscription per topic? There's question talking about subscription in order to use one bus namespace for many application with SubscriptionEndpoint. Should I post new question

Comment: If you want to separate the traffic so that dev spaces are isolated, using uniquely prefixed topics/queues per dev space is recommended.

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't find any docs on how to deal with topic/queues/subscription in Mass Transit.

Comment: For what specific parts?

Comment: I'm writing a new SO fully detailed SO question. Thank you for your support, the framework is amazing